# Next steps to supplement home gym routine?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, gym, home-exercise, you-are-your-own-gym

I've now got a three piece home gym... A doorframe mounted pull-up bar, a gymform abxelerate spring loaded sit-up machine, and some makeshift dip bars. My routine has basically become one or two sets of 15-40 sit-ups on the abcelerate, and 1-3 sets of 5-10 dips each, although I ether have to tilt my body backwards as I come down so that my front of torso is slightly facing down rather than fully vertical as it is when I lift myself up, or I have to raise my knees nearly into the fetal position like suspended upward with knees and hips  both bent to the max like a crunch that leaves me in a ball. One of these or the offer is necessary to let me go down all the way. Then whenever I see the doorframe mounted pull-up bar and think of it, I try to do 10 pull-ups, though usually exhaust by about 8. I usually do them with my palms and inner forearms facing back toward me. Occasionally I also hang for a minute, but in all cases it isn't high enough for me to completely dangle my legs to as with the dips I must always bend my knees and lift my feet and lower legs.

Since I got these machines I've stopped doing regular push-ups and tricep dips, but there's no reason why I can't. I've also contemplated getting dumbbells and using the abcelerate as a bench.

But in any case I miss lifting heavy weights and dadlifting barbells in the gym.

What could I do to add some further variety to this routine, and maybe more significantly, what would be the highest priority missing things to supplement it with at the gym if I was to go back in once or twice a week?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on what are your goals.

For a full body training you're missing:

- horizontal / vertical presses (bench press / shoulder press)
- horizontal pull (back rows)
- legs (squat variations / leg extension + curl)
- hip hinge (romanian deadlift)

You could solve those with either barbells + plates or dumbbells, they both have its own advantages and disadvantages.

Either way I'd get at least a flat / adjustable bench for the presses (I got a foldable one to save space when I'm not using it).